# Search field is missing in JHipster

Tags: jhipster

1. I generated the JHipster application frontend and backend separately. 
   jhipster --skip-client
   jhipster --skip-server --db=sql --auth=jwt
2. Imported jdl file to frontend and backend.
   jhipster import-jdl 21poindt.jh --skip-client
   jhipster import-jdl 21points.jh --skip-server
3. Backend and frontend run with no error.
4. CRUD functionalities of generated entities work fine, **BUT THE SEARCH FIELD IS MISSING**.
5. When I generated JHipster with the same jdl file, and backend and frontend together, the search field appears as it is expected.

**What I did wrong? How can I enable the search field in separate JHispter frontend?**

```
entity Points {
    date LocalDate required,
    exercise Integer,
    meals Integer,
    alcohol Integer,
    notes String maxlength(140)
}

entity Weight {
    timestamp ZonedDateTime required,
    weight Double required
}

entity BloodPressure {
    timestamp ZonedDateTime required,
    systolic Integer required,
    diastolic Integer required
}

entity Preferences {
    weeklyGoal Integer required min(10) max(21),
    weightUnits Units required
}

enum Units {
    KG, LB
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Preferences{user(login)} to User
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    BloodPressure{user(login)} to User,
    Weight{user(login)} to User,
    Points{user(login)} to User
}

// Set pagination options
paginate BloodPressure, Weight with infinite-scroll
paginate Points with pagination

// Use Data Transfert Objects (DTO)
dto * with mapstruct

// Set service options to all except few
service all with serviceImpl

filter Points
```

Comment: Is `"searchEngine": "elasticsearch"` present in both your frontend and backend `.yo-rc.json` files?  Also have you tried enabling the `search` option in the JDL? https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/options

Answer (score 2):

@JonRuddell When I generated JHipster frontend with --skip-server I was not asked about the elasticsearch. After your comment, I have added "searchEngine": "elasticsearch" to .yo-rc.json and regenerated app. Now it shows the search field. Thanks